# safely shrinking /var/cache on Debian 7.8

Tags: linux, debian, cache, storage

Here are the top storage resource hogs on my single-user home system, which is a customized version of Debian 7.8 with lxde-core optional but no graphical login manager:

```
3487080 .
1732560 ./usr
1050128 ./home
1050124 ./home/[user]
845396  ./usr/share
702324  ./home/[user]/.rvm
687536  ./usr/lib
531372  ./var
350876  ./var/cache
349036  ./home/[user]/.rvm/src
```

The bloat caused by Ruby Volume Manager is unavoidable, but /var/cache is unnecessarily huge. I've done some reading and am now afraid to clear /var/cache manually so I don't break my system. What can people suggest?

Answer (score 0):

`/var/cache` *should be* safe to delete, see [FHS](https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/fhs/fhs-2.3.html#VARCACHEAPPLICATIONCACHEDATA%20FHS), however, its re-creation may be time-consuming.

To be on the safer side, you may temporarily move the contents `/var/cache/*` out of the way and remove it if nothing bad happens.